# I keep getting an error when i run this query. Anyone see where i messed up at?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [property usage], 
       [total], 
       [todate], 
       [todateorder], 
       [purpose of loan], 
       [marital status], 
       [agegroup], 
       [race], 
       [sex], 
       Datepart(mm, loandate)                          LoanMonth, 
       Datepart(yy, loandate)                          LoanYear, 
       Avg(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), monthlyincome))     AvgMonthlyIncome, 
       Avg(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), loanamount))        AvgLoanAmount, 
       Sum(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), monthlyincome) / 
           CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), loanamount) 
       )                                               MonthlyIncomeVSLoanAmount 
       , 
       @MTD                                            MTD, 
       @MonthlyPrior6mnthAvg                           MonthlyPrior6mnthAvg, 
       ( ( @MTD * 1.00 ) / @MonthlyPrior6mnthAvg ) * 100 
       MTDvsMonthlyPrior6mnth_Avg_PerInc, 
       @LastFullMonth                                  LastFullMonth, 
       @MonthlyPrior6mnthAvgExcludeCurrMonth 
       MonthlyPrior6mnthAvgExcludeCurrMonth, 
       ( ( @LastFullMonth * 1.00 ) / @MonthlyPrior6mnthAvgExcludeCurrMonth ) * 
       100 
       LastFullMonthvsMonthlyPrior6mnthExcludeCurrMonthAvg_PerInc, 
       @QTD                                            QTD, 
       @LastFullQuarter                                LastFullQuarter, 
       ( ( @QTD * 1.00 ) / @LastFullQuarter ) * 100    QTDvsLastFullQuarter, 
       ( Datename(month, loandate) + ' ' 
         + Datename(year, loandate) )                  ReportMonth, 
       [borrowername]                                  NAME, 
       loanamount, 
       [purchase price], 
       [monthlyincome], 
       Datename(month, loandate)                       MonthName, 
       ( [borrowername] + ' ' + '(' + [loan_id] + ')' )Name2
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_LoansProcessed_ToDate, Line
>   178 [Batch Start Line 7] Conversion failed when converting the varchar
>   value ')' to data type int.

Comment: Simplify the query to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: That SQL is a mess, and your formatting and lack of whitespace makes it unreadable. Start there. It's extremely difficult to debug or maintain code when it's written so poorly.

Comment: Probably this bit  ([BorrowerName]+' '+'('+[Loan_ID]+')')Name2 assuming loan_id is an int you will need to convert it to character type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change last line of your query to -

```
( [borrowername] + ' ' + '(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),[loan_id]) + ')' )Name2
```

Note - Replace NVARCHAR(10) in above line as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error when concatenating [Loan_ID]+')' in

```
([BorrowerName]+' '+'('+[Loan_ID]+')') Name2
```

use concat function

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `loan_Id` to `varchar`

```
( [borrowername] + ' ' + '(' + [loan_id] + ')' ) Name2
```

to

```
[borrowername] + ' ' + '(' + [cast(loan_id as varchar(50))] + ')' as Name2
```

when concatenating `int` with any `string`, sql engine will implicitly convert the string to int, since `int` has higher precedence than `varchar`. So you need to explicitly convert the `loan_id` to `varchar` to avoid this issue

Also I just removed the unwanted parenthesis to make the code look cleaner